# Github Webhook on Local Jenkins Server

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to know is it possible to set a Github Webhook on Local Jenkins Server? Is there any Jenkins plugin to solve this kind of problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[Yes, it is possible](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration), however you'll need to connect your local Jenkins server to the internet, using a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs#expose).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By the way, is there any alternatives beside ngrok in order to connect our local Jenkins server?

Comment: @fauzanrazandi, I know it's been almost two years since this question was asked but for anyone researching this, it looks like serveo.net is the best solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

I have searched a lot to configure my local `jenkins server` with `Github Webhook`and finally with the help of [serveo.net](http://serveo.net/) make it work by following below steps -

1. Open terminal and paste command: `ssh -R 80:<localhost_with_port_number> serveo.net`

   > e.g. ssh -R 80:127.0.0.1:8080 serveo.net
2. It will give you an accessible url -

   [image]
3. Your local jenkins server will be accessible on given url -

   [image]
4. Use this url in your webhook configuration -

   [image]

   Now your local jenkins server is ready to test any CICD activity...

   > Note: Each time it may generate a different url and in that case you have to update webhook configuration.

   Happy learning!

Comment: this solution not working for me as the website already down or not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

In your Jenkins server, Go to “Manage Jenkins” -> “Manage Plugins” as shown below:
[image]

Search for GitHub plugin in the available list of plugins and install it, as shown below.

[image]

Next go to your GitHub project's settings, click the webhooks tab on the left as shown below and add the Jenkins GitHub plugin's webhook URL there.

[image]

Everytime, a Git pull or Git push event happens, GitHub will send a HTTP Post notification to your Jenkins server via the GitHub plugin.

You need a service like [SocketXP](https://www.socketxp.com/webhookrelay/github-jenkins-webhook-relay/) to interconnect online GitHub or GitLab or Bitbucket project with your Jenkins server running in your local network or in your private cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Using ngrok:

1. Download ngrok form https://ngrok.com/download
2. Then go the destination folder where your ngrok zip file present .
3. Extract the zip file.
4. Open Cmd and type `ngrok.exe http 8080` and hit enter.
5. Then you see like:

   ```
   Web Interface       http://127.0.0.1:4040
   Forwarding   https://12c8-27-147-128-18.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:8080.
   ```
6. Copy https://12c8-27-147-128-18.ngrok-free.app and paste to add webhook on your git.